# Why does Chrome allow this silent Azure OAuth authorization request but not Firefox and Edge?

Tags: azure, google-chrome, firefox, oauth-2.0, microsoft-edge

**Background**

1. Webapp (SPA + WebAPI) uses Azure + OAuth + OpenID Connect to authenticate and authorize the user.
2. OAuth Implicit flow.
3. Once the access token expires, I call the Azure OAuth authorization end point to silently request a new access_token.
4. Authorization endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

---

**Authorization Request**

The URL to do the silent authorization request is (formatted for readability)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?response_type=token id_token
&client_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
&state=123
&scope=openid api://xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/user_impersonation
&redirect_uri=https://my-app.azurewebsites.net/index.html
&nonce=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
&prompt=none
```

---

**Response**

The response from all 3 browsers is a 302. But the location header in the response differs.

**Chrome** location (formatted for readability)

```
https://my-app.azurewebsites.net/index.html
#access_token=...
&token_type=Bearer
&expires_in=3599
&scope=api://xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/user_impersonation
&id_token=...
&state=123
&session_state=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Edge / Firefox** location

```
https://my-app.azurewebsites.net/index.html
#error=login_required
&error_description=AADSTS50058 A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in. The cookies used to represent the users session were not sent in the request to Azure AD. This can happen if the user is using Internet Explorer or Edge and the web app sending the silent sign-in request is in different IE security zone than the Azure AD endpoint (login.microsoftonline.com). Trace ID xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxCorrelation ID xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx Timestamp 2020-01-24 08:17:33
&error_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50058
&state=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

---

**Error message** (from Edge / Firefox response)

```
A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in. 
The cookies used to represent the users session were not sent in the request to Azure AD. 
This can happen if the user is using Internet Explorer or Edge 
and the web app sending the silent sign-in request is in different
IE security zone than the Azure AD endpoint (login.microsoftonline.com).
```

The message from the error URI https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50058 is

```
Session information is not sufficient for single-sign-on.
This means that a user is not signed in. 
This is a common error that's expected when a user is unauthenticated and has not yet signed in. 
If this error is encountered in an SSO context where the user has previously signed in, 
this means that the SSO session was either not found or invalid. 
This error may be returned to the application if prompt=none is specified
```

---

**Cookies**

I noticed the cookies sent and received by Chrome differ from the cookies sent and received by Edge / Firefox.

**Chrome** request cookies (17)

```
x-ms-gateway-slice=...; 
stsservicecookie=...; 
AADSSO=...; 
esctx=...; 
brcap=.; 
clrc=...; 
wlidperf=...; 
MSCC=...; 
ESTSAUTHLIGHT=...; 
ESTSSC=...;
ESTSAUTHPERSISTENT=...;
ESTSAUTH=...; 
ch=...; 
buid=...;
CCState=...;
SignInStateCookie=...;
fpc=...
```

**Chrome** response cookies (11)

```
ESTSAUTHPERSISTENT=...; domain=.login.microsoftonline.com; expires=Thu, 23-Apr-2020 08:18:32 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
ESTSAUTH=...; domain=.login.microsoftonline.com; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
ESTSAUTHLIGHT=...; path=/; secure; SameSite=None
ch=...; domain=.login.microsoftonline.com; expires=Thu, 23-Apr-2020 08:18:32 GMT; path=/; secure; SameSite=None
ESTSSC=...; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
buid=...; expires=Sun, 23-Feb-2020 08:18:32 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
CCState=...; domain=.login.microsoftonline.com; expires=Sun, 23-Feb-2020 08:13:32 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
SignInStateCookie=...; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
fpc=...; expires=Sun, 23-Feb-2020 08:18:32 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
x-ms-gateway-slice=...; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly
stsservicecookie=...; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
```

No request cookies in **Edge / Firefox**.

**Edge / Firefox** response cookies (4)

```
buid=...; expires=Sun, 23-Feb-2020 08:24:39 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
fpc=...; expires=Sun, 23-Feb-2020 08:24:39 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
x-ms-gateway-slice=...; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly
stsservicecookie=...; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly
```

---

**Versions**

- Chrome version: 79.0.3945.130
- Edge version: 44.18362.449.0
- Firefox version: 72.0.2

---

**Questions**

1. Why does Chrome allow this call to https://login.microsoftonline.com to silently request an access token but on Firefox and Edge the call fails?
2. Why does Chrome include the above requests cookies but not Firefox and Edge?

Comment: I will try to discuss the issue with senior engineers and try to know their opinion on this issue. I will try to provide the information as soon as I get any feedback from them. Thanks for your understanding.